# Are there any approximation methods to solve indefinite integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods, indefinite-integrals, numerical-calculus

I am aware of various numerical methods for solving definite integrals like Gauss Quadrature rule, Traezoidal rule, Simpson rules etc. But I could not find any such numerical methods in the literature for approximating indefinite integrals.

Question: Are there any approximation methods for solving indefinite integrals?

Comment: If the function has a usable Taylor or Laurent series, the antiderivative is immediate. Polynomial and trigonometric approximations will work as well.

Comment: If the integral is sufficiently difficult in multiple dimensions, Monte Carlo Integration is sometimes used.

Answer (score 2):

Sure... You can approximate the integral $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$ by any numerical quadrature of your liking. This way you can determine $F(x)$ for any particular $x$ using a quadrature on the interval $[a,x]$.